# C++ Multithreading - algorithm

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm

I'm trying develop a sudoku solver with a backtracking algorithm. I also want to use multithreading.

The code will compile however the program crashes after executing the method.

There it is:

code snippets from Backtracking.cpp, all methods are defined in Backtracking.h

**The following three methods eheck a position (x, y) within a matrix whether it is possible to set a new value (value) there.**

```
// this function checks the horizontal line of a 9x9-matrix

int Backtracking::checkHorizontal(int y, int value){  

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(fieldProtect);
        if(field[y][i] == value)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

// this function checks the vertical line of a 9x9-matrix

int Backtracking::checkVertical(int x, int value){    

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(fieldProtect);
        if(field[i][x] == value)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

// this function checks the 3x3 box within a 9x9-matrix

int Backtracking::checkBox(int x, int y, int value){  

    int x_box, y_box, i, j;


    x_box = (int)(x / 3) * 3;
    y_box = (int)(y / 3) * 3;

    for(i = y_box; i < y_box + 3; i++)
        for(j = x_box; j < x_box + 3; j++)

            if(field[i][j] == value)
                return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

**THIS IS WHERE the three upper private-methods are called**

```
int Backtracking::check(int x, int y, int value){   

    std::future<int> fCells = std::async(std::launch::async, &Backtracking::checkBox,
                                          this, std::ref(x), std::ref(y), std::ref(value));
    std::future<int> fRows = std::async(std::launch::async, &Backtracking::checkHorizontal,
                                         this, std::ref(y), std::ref(value));
    std::future<int> fCols = std::async(std::launch::async, &Backtracking::checkVertical,
                                         this, std::ref(x), std::ref(value));


    if(fRows.get()){
        return 1;
    }
    if(fCols.get()){
        return 1;
    }
    if(fCells.get()){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0; // everything oK

}
```

**WHITHIN THIS Method the check-method is called, therefore I think this is what crashes the program.**

```
int Backtracking::solve(int x, int y)
{
    int i;


    if(x == 9){                                    
        y++;                                       
        x = 0;


        if(y == 9){                                     

            return 1;
        }
    }

    if(field[y][x] > 0){                             

        return solve(x+1, y);
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= 9; i++){                        

        if(!check(x, y, i)){                        // THIS IS WHERE THE check-Function is called!
            field[y][x] = i;                         

            if(solve(x+1, y)){                      
                transfer();                        
            }
        }
    }

    field[y][x] = 0;                                 
    return 0;
}
```

I programed a similar program the same way and it worked fine. Since I'm new to concurrent programming I don't see the problem there.

I hope some you guys see the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Mark

**edit: It seems as if this code will continue creating thread over thread without finishing...**

Testing-Console-App:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <vector>

#include <mutex>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>


class Backtracking{

public:

    Backtracking();

    ~Backtracking();

    /**
     * @brief starts sudoku solver
     * @return
     */
    bool solveSudoku();

    /**
     * @brief prints the Sudoku to the console
     */
    void printSudoku();

    void printSolvedSudoku();

private:

    /**
     * \brief matrix 9x9
     * \details
     */
    int field[9][9] = {{0,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,0},
                       {0,4,0,5,0,1,0,3,0},
                       {5,0,0,8,0,9,0,0,2},
                       {0,2,7,0,0,0,9,1,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,3,9,0,0,0,4,5,0},
                       {3,0,0,1,0,4,0,0,6},
                       {0,1,0,2,0,6,0,7,0},
                       {0,0,6,0,0,0,5,0,0}};

    /**
     * \brief solved Matrix 9x9
     */
    int solvedField[9][9];

    /**
     * \brief calls all check...-Methods
     */
    int check(const int x, const int y, const int wert);


    int checkHorizontal(int y, int value) const;

    int checkVertical(int x, int value) const;

    int checkBox(int x, int y, int wert) const;

    /**
     * \brief transfers sudoku to solvedField
     */
    void transfer();

    /**
     * \brief solver
     */
    int solve(int x, int y);

};

int Backtracking::checkHorizontal(int y, int value) const{

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        if(field[y][i] == value)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

int Backtracking::checkVertical(int x, int value) const{

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        if(field[i][x] == value)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

int Backtracking::checkBox(int const x, int const y, int const value) const{
    int x_box, y_box, i, j;

    x_box = (int)(x / 3) * 3;
    y_box = (int)(y / 3) * 3;

    for(i = y_box; i < y_box + 3; i++)
        for(j = x_box; j < x_box + 3; j++)

            if(field[i][j] == value)
                return 1;
    return 0;
}

int Backtracking::check(int x, int y, int value){
    std::future<int> fCells = std::async(std::launch::async, &Backtracking::checkBox,
                                          this, x, y, value);
    std::future<int> fRows = std::async(std::launch::async, &Backtracking::checkHorizontal,
                                         this, y, value);
    std::future<int> fCols = std::async(std::launch::async, &Backtracking::checkVertical,
                                         this, x, value);

    if(fCells.get()){
        return 1;
    }
    if(fRows.get()){
        return 1;
    }
    if(fCols.get()){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

    /*if(checkBox(x, y, value)){
        return 1;
    }
    if(checkHorizontal(y, value)){
        return 1;
    }
    if(checkVertical(x, value)){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;*/

}

void Backtracking::transfer(){

    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            solvedField[i][j] = field[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int Backtracking::solve(int x, int y)
{
    int i;


    if(x == 9){
        y++;
        x = 0;

        if(y == 9){
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if(field[y][x] > 0){           // already solved
        return solve(x+1, y);
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= 9; i++){

        if(!check(x, y, i)){
            field[y][x] = i;

            if(solve(x+1, y)){
                transfer();
            }
        }
    }

    field[y][x] = 0;
    return 0;
}

bool Backtracking::solveSudoku(){



    if (solve(0,0) == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;


}

Backtracking::Backtracking()
{

}



Backtracking::~Backtracking()
{

}

void Backtracking::printSudoku(){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for(j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            std::cout << this->field[i][j] << "  ";
        }
    }
}

void Backtracking::printSolvedSudoku(){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for(j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            std::cout << this->solvedField[i][j] << "  ";
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Backtracking* ba = new Backtracking();

    ba->printSudoku();
    ba->solveSudoku();
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    ba->printSolvedSudoku();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Could you post a stack trace, too?

Comment: Better to add const to your check methods, and `std::ref` is misleading as your methods take `int` by value (so remove useless `std::ref`).

Comment: Debug the code and let it tell you the exact line that causes the problem. Then let us know which is it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers: I get this error message about a hundred times :) when I debug the code:                        RTTI symbol not found for class 'std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<int (Backtracking::*)(int, int, int)> (Backtracking*, int, int, int)>, int>, std::allocator<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<int (Backtracking::*)(int, int, int)> (Backtracking*, int, int, int)>, int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> @Jarod42: Do you mean it that way:check(int const x, int const y, ...

Comment: @mark: I mean `int Backtracking::checkHorizontal(int y, int value) const`.

Comment: Could you post a `main`-driven (failing) unit test, with the full source in a single file? That would make it way easier for us to try to help.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I added a console-testing-application where the error occurs. The application seems to create threads without ever finishing. Might be a problem because of the recursive algorithm. However when the check-functions are called within the check method it works fine...

Comment: @mark in that case it could be that 2 or more semaphores/locks/mutex/whatever are waiting for each other. usually adding some well placed sleep or own check before shared variable access helps but not always. For heavy duty multithread access is sometimes better to use own lock with access que/scheduling so you avoid this permanent lock. Another way is use watchdog and force unlock or kill thread but that is not algorithm safe and should be used as last resort. The best way is use non locking access but that is not always possible. Also beware of timing because it is OS dependent